# issue in use of select box in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

i want to know how dropdown menu or select box working .... here is my code for select box

```
   <select class="browser-default" id="com" name="company" >
   <option value="{{$employee->company->id}}" disabled selected>{{$employee-
   >company->name}}</option>
   @foreach($compnies as $company)
   <option value="{{$company->id}}" >{{$company->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
   </select><br>
```

here i want to update my data but some time user can not change the select box data and keep previous in this case how can i save my by default selected data in drop box ..... 
here is my controller update function ..

```
        $employee->name = $request->input('name');
        $employee->father_name  = $request->input('father_name');
        $employee->mobile = $request->input('mobile');
        $employee->address = $request->input('address');
        $employee->site_id= $request->site;
        $employee->company_id = $request->company;
        $employee->save();
```

so basically i want if user do not want to change the select option .... and change other data like mobile ... then how can i keep my old option of select box which is already selected or by default selected .....

Comment: what is $employee->company->id? isn't it $employee->company_id ?

Comment: no its a relation between employee and company ....

Comment: and why you made it disabled?

Comment: Are you using jquery

Comment: i use this in my previous project that's why disabled here but there is not matter ....

Comment: no i am not using jquery ...... i just use simple html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
   <select class="browser-default" id="com" name="company" >
         @foreach($compnies as $company)
          <option value="{{$company->id}}" {{ $company->id ==  $employee->company_id ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{$company->name}}</option>
         @endforeach
  </select>
```